# Объединить ячейки таблицы при th td с помощью css

Tags: css, табличная-верстка

Возможно ли объединить ячейки таблицы только с помощью `css`? Нужно чтобы `заголовок` был наверху, `текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст` начинался с новой строки и был во всю ширину таблицы, соответственно все в одной ячейке и только с помощью `css`.

```html
 
    <table class="table_class" border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="pclaaf">Заголовок контент</th>
   <th class="pral">Текст контент</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
      <tr class="carem">
     <td class="prome">
      Заголовок контент      </td>
     <td class="prootal">
      Текст контент     </td>
     </tr>
         <tr class="carem">
     <td class="prome">
      Заголовок контент      </td>
     <td class="prootal">
      Текст контент     </td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
 <tfoot>
   <tr class="tr_class">
<th>Заголовок</th>
<td>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст </td>
</tr>
     <tr class="feef">
    <th>Заголовок контент</th>
    <td>Текст контент</td>
   </tr>       
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Только с помощью `css`, не влезая в код!

Comment: Нет вы не поняли, сейчас напишу полный код.

Comment: @Ubuntu User Смотрите вопрос.

Comment: Я все таки думаю что возможно. Почти у каждой строки свой стиль и придумать можно.

Comment: Потому что разметка в woocommerce где то глубоко зарыта в функциях и шаблону не поддается.

Comment: Глупости искажать конкретно поставленный вопрос. С такой логикой можно и свой движок написать. Но речь идет именно о `css` и кому то следовало бы для начала изучить `css`, а потом умничать.

Comment: я не спорю но через css изменять табличную вёрстку можно  если перепилить плоностью

Comment: Ниже дан ответ на поставленный вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересно можно сделать как то так:

```css
   

.table_class {width: 50%;}

.table_class tfoot .tr_class { width: 126%;}
.tr_class th {display: inline-block;} 
.tr_class {display: inline-block;border: 2px solid #ff0000;}
```

```html
  

  <table class="table_class" border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="pclaaf">Заголовок контент</th>
   <th class="pral">Текст контент</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
      <tr class="carem">
     <td class="prome">
      Заголовок контент      </td>
     <td class="prootal">
      Текст контент     </td>
     </tr>
         <tr class="carem">
     <td class="prome">
      Заголовок контент      </td>
     <td class="prootal">
      Текст контент     </td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
 <tfoot>
   <tr class="tr_class">
<th>Заголовок</th>
<td>текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст </td>
</tr>
     <tr class="feef">
    <th>Заголовок контент</th>
    <td>Текст контент</td>
   </tr>       
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: логично вы сделали - но это уже не таблица